# PyPDF2 IndexError: index out of range

Tags: python, pypdf

I'll start with I'm very new to using Python and PyPDF. I'm trying to collect all of the fields within a pdf to collect into a dataframe.  Eventually I want to collect thousands of PDFs that all have the same structure (form) as the baseline and place them into the PDF.  I was able to get this code to work great on a PDF without a digital certificate/signature.  However, when I run the code on a PDF with the digital certificate/signature I get an error.

I don't really need the digital signature/certificate spot of the document so I think the easiest way to do this is to just skip that field of the PDF.  However, I don't know how to do that since the PyPDF2 package looks at every field.

Code:

```
import os
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
import pandas as pd

directory = 'files'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f)
        pdf=pypdf.PdfFileReader(f, strict= False)
        print(pdf)
        #information = pdf.getFormTextFields()
        information = pdf.getFields()
        print(information)
        output = pd.DataFrame([information])
        df = pd.concat([df, output], ignore_index=True)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/app.py", line 77, in <module>
    information = pdf.getFields()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 526, in getFields
    return self.get_fields(tree, retval, fileobj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 510, in get_fields
    self._build_field(field, retval, fileobj, field_attributes)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 535, in _build_field
    self._check_kids(field, retval, fileobj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 555, in _check_kids
    self.get_fields(kid.get_object(), retval, fileobj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 499, in get_fields
    self._check_kids(tree, retval, fileobj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 555, in _check_kids
    self.get_fields(kid.get_object(), retval, fileobj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 503, in get_fields
    self._build_field(tree, retval, fileobj, field_attributes)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 547, in _build_field
    retval[key] = Field(field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 1626, in __init__
    self[NameObject(attr)] = data[attr]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key).get_object()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 251, in get_object
    obj = self.pdf.get_object(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_reader.py", line 1167, in get_object
    retval, indirect_reference.idnum, indirect_reference.generation
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_encryption.py", line 741, in decrypt_object
    return cf.decrypt_object(obj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_encryption.py", line 182, in decrypt_object
    obj[dictkey] = self.decrypt_object(value)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_encryption.py", line 185, in decrypt_object
    obj[i] = self.decrypt_object(obj[i])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_encryption.py", line 182, in decrypt_object
    obj[dictkey] = self.decrypt_object(value)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_encryption.py", line 176, in decrypt_object
    data = self.strCrypt.decrypt(obj.original_bytes)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/_encryption.py", line 88, in decrypt
    return d[: -d[-1]]
IndexError: index out of range
```

Comment: At a first glance, it looks to me that this would be better suited on the PyPDF2 issue tracker: https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll submit the question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an update.  I was able to get around the error by doing this:

```py
import os
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
import pandas as pd

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f)
        pdf=pypdf.PdfFileReader(f, strict= False)
        try:
            information = pdf.getFields()           
            #information = pdf.getFields()
        except: 
            pass

        print(information)
        output = pd.DataFrame([information])
        df = pd.concat([df, output], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Try executing your code with `python -Wall`. This will show a lot of deprecation warnings. One thing you should change is replacing `PdfFileReader` by `PdfReader`. They mostly behave the same, but `PdfReader` has by default `strict=False`